# Youtube API Iframe On Click

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I really need some help with Youtube API.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function(){
var player;

var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
var $$ = function(tagname) {
  return document.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
}

var $$$ = function(classname) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(classname);
}

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var videos = $$('iframe'), // the iframes elements
    players = [], // an array where we stock each videos youtube instances class
    playingID = null; // stock the current playing video
  for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) // for each iframes
  {
    var currentIframeID = videos[i].id; // we get the iframe ID
    players[currentIframeID] = new YT.Player(currentIframeID); // we stock in the array the instance
    // note, the key of each array element will be the iframe ID

    videos[i].onmouseover = function(e) { // assigning a callback for this event
      var currentHoveredElement = e.target;
      if (playingID) // if a video is currently played
      {
        players[playingID].stopVideo();
      }
      players[currentHoveredElement.id].playVideo();

      playingID = currentHoveredElement.id;
    };
    videos[i].onmouseout = function(e) { // assigning a callback for this event
      var currentHoveredElement = e.target;
      players[playingID].stopVideo();
      playingID = currentHoveredElement.id;
    };

  }

}
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();

}> 
</script>
```

This is the Script, and for the PHP

```
$i = 1;
  foreach($data['items'] as $child) {
  $i++;

<iframe id="player<?php echo $i; ?>" width="270" height="180" data-src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $child['id']['videoId']; ?>?rel=0&wmode=Opaque&enablejsapi=1;showinfo=0;controls=0;autohide=1;modestbranding=1;showsearch=0;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="position:relative;"></iframe>

}
```

It'll show the videos from youtube, and whenever you hover, it is autoplaying, onmouseout the video is stopping. But what i wanted to do is if hovered and clicked the iframe video, it goes to http://www.google.com/ link.

How am i supposed to do it? 
Thanks in advance Guys.